# best URL validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, uri

im using code as below to check for the URL validation:

```
 public static bool CheckURLValid(string strURL)
  {
       Uri uriResult;
       return Uri.TryCreate(strURL, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult) && uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
  }
```

The result as below should show all as **true**, but somehow it has its own pattern to validate the url:

**false**: google.com

**true**: http://www.google.com

**false**: https://www.google.com.my/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=check%20if%20valid%20url%20c%23

**true**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

im using c#, how to enhance this checking url validation to be more accurate?

Comment: Why third one should be *false* ? It is a valid URL and it works indeed.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I read the question as they should all be true, but the code shown returns the above results, so they believe 3 should be valid too.

Comment: yes, it suppose to return true, but somehow my function return it as false :( sorry for my poor english

Comment: @DanielKelley Oops. Misread it. Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at Uri.IsWellFormedUriString?  It looks like you are just re implementing it.  also for the #3 it is returning false because of checking for HTTP with `&& uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp`.  #3 is httpS

Comment: @WindRaven please see my reply on Tonci's answer :)

Comment: @user3431239, I saw it and just updated with more info.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your CheckURLValid is returning exactly what you have told it to.

To return True on all 4 URLs here are the issues

false: google.com

This is a relative url and you have specified  UriKind.Absolute which means this is false.

false: https://www.google.com.my/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=check%20if%20valid%20url%20c%23

This is an httpS (Secure) url and your method says

```
&& uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp;
```

which will limit you to only http addresses (NON secure)

To get the results you are wanting you will need to use the following method:

```
public static bool CheckURLValid(string strURL)
{
    Uri uriResult;
    return Uri.TryCreate(strURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uriResult);
}
```

An alternative is to just use

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(strURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

and not re implement functionality that all ready exists.  If you wanted to wrap it it your own CheckUrlValid I would use the following:

```
public static bool CheckURLValid(string strURL)
{
    return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(strURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); ;
}
```

The main problem is that most strings are valid relative URL's so I would avoid using UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute as google.com is an invalid url.  Most web browsers silently add HTTP:// to the string to make it a valid url.  `HTTP://google.com` is a valid url.

Comment: thank you for the answer, i stick with Absolute. and this is my final code: return Uri.TryCreate(strURL, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult); i do some control to ensure users to key in 'http/https' in order to proceed.

Comment: System.Uri only recognizes urls up to 263 chars long. Standard says anything up to 2000 chars should be supported

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if I'm missing something here, but just so others don't waste their time with `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString`, note that the following test fails:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestURLValidation()
{
    bool result = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString("bad", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}
```

I.e., the prescribed answer will consider "bad" as a valid address. I believe that's not the behavior most users are after.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
var isUrl = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(strURL, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
```

It returns **true** on all four strings you wrote in your question.

Comment: thx for the reply, i tried 'IsWellFormedUriString' before i come across with 'Uri.TryCreate', it doesn't helped me, because it return the result as true even though it obviously not a valid url. you can try to key in with any string and see the result, eg: ahskdjfh

Comment: The problem is that "google" (or any other string that consists only of english letters) and "google.com" are equally valid URLs. They are both valid as relative URLs, but not as absolute URLs.

Comment: There are other problems, too.  For example, using ??? will return true.  (when using UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute or UriKind.Relative)

Answer (score 1):

This is the best solution without using Regex:

(note that for example using only "IsWellFormedUriString" will return true for "//")

```
    public static bool IsValidUrl(string url)
    {
        if (url == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            Uri uriResult = new Uri(url);
            return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

For unit testing you can check the [link](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) where my function got nice results.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by writing a small helper method that uses Regex to validate the url.

**The following URL's pass:**

google.com

www.google.com

http://google.com

http://www.google.com

https://google.com/test/test

https://www.google.com/test

**It fails on:**

www.google.com/a bad path with white space/

**Below is the helper method I created:**

```
    public static bool ValidateUrl(string value, bool required, int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        value = value.Trim();
        if (required == false && value == "") return true;
        if (required && value == "") return false;

        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$");
        Match match = pattern.Match(value);
        if (match.Success == false) return false;
        return true;
    }
```

**This allows users to input any valid url, plus it accounts for bad url paths with white space which is exactly what I needed. I hope this helps someone**