# Check if API URL is valid - POST call

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I need to allow user to enter a remote API URL with basic authentication/ or a static token to POST the data from my application to the URL at specified intervals.

I tried setting the "HEAD" only but it does the GET operation and throws 405 - Method Not Allowed error for all the requests.

I would like to know if there is any way to validate the URL and the credentials with given POST URL.

I understand I can valid the the URL but my concern is to ensure that I need to validate the basic auth credentials entered by the user is also correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [best URL validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049416/best-url-validation)

Comment: @Set I am not just validating the URL but also I need to confirm the auth credentials are correct. The given link will doesn't speak about auth credentials.

Answer (score -1):

Try this-

```
try
            {
                WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("YOUR API URL");
                tRequest.Method = "post";
                tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                var data = new
                {
                   //REQUIERED PARAMETERIZED DATA
                };
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", ApplicationID));
                tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("YOUR HEADER"));
                tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                        using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                            using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                            {
                                String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                                str = sResponseFromServer;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                str = ex.Message;
            }
```

Comment: what this will do?