# How to do server and client side validation which should only accept URL in textbox?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to do client and server side validation for Textbox which should only accept `URL`. I am not able find any link which does the same.

Can anyone please provide some ideas?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => URl })
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049416/best-url-validation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717093/check-if-a-javascript-string-is-a-url

Comment: @devlincarnate, How to implement that code in my scenario. I have model where I have properties called `URl`. I do not understand how to do. please show me some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a `UrlAttribute` in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` that you can apply to your property to give both client and server side validation.

```
[Url] // Add optional (ErrorMessage = "...") as required
public string Url { get; set; }
```

Internally, it uses the following regex (from [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/UrlAttribute.cs))

> ^(https?|ftp)://(((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).?)(:\d*)?)(/((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)+(/(([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|/|\?)*)?$

Comment: Thank you Stephen. It helped me.

Comment: It does not accept `www.google.com` or `google.com`. I want to implement this type of url also.

Comment: @MVC, The `[Url]` attribute is based on a valid url (which includes the protocol - e.g. `http`). If you want to allow just `google.com` (I would not recommend it), then you would need to use a [RegularExpression]` attribute - [this one](https://www.regextester.com/93652) should be suitable

Comment: Thank you Stephen. I will then take your recommendation. I will not implement like  `www.google.com`. I will use the `Url` attribute only.

Answer (score 1):

You can do URL Validation using regex for validation.

> ^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$

OR

> /^http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?$/

You can this regex in both Server-Side and Javascript.

check it on :   [JSFIDDLE](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/0rq4k6a8/185/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegularExpression validation in your model:

```
[StringLength(200)]
[RegularExpression(@"((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid website URL")]
public string MyUrlField { get; set; }
```

I have found the above regex for matching a url from [here](http://rubular.com/r/ubZM1E6vol). You could also check [this website](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex) for other regex which would match a url.

Note that you need to include [jquery-validation-unobtrusive](https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-validation-unobtrusive), for the client side validation.